# Overriding facebook comments css

Tags: facebook

I have a black web page at yourcashflowpros.com that integrates with fb comments. Fb comments looks like $&%! against a black bg, can someone tell me if i can change the css on the comments or should I just change the background to make it look right?

Thanks
Todd

Answer (score 4):

Well, its in an iframe so your css wouldn't affect it.  The easy approach would be to make the background container of your fb:comments block white (with a little padding on left and right), that would make the comments block look right.

change

```
<fb:comments width="900"></fb:comments>
```

to

```
<fb:comments width="900" style="background-color: white; padding 10px;"></fb:comments>
```

Answer (score 4):

The fb:comments tag has a css attribute you can specify to pull in your external stylesheet.

```
<fb:comments numposts="4" title="My Blog Comments" css="http://www.yourwebsite.com/css/comments.css?1234" simple="1"></fb:comments>
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/comments_(XFBML)/

Comment: having the following ›› `<fb:comments href="{current_url}" num_posts="0" width="380px" height="100px" css="http://{working_url_and_path}/fb_comments.css?12" simple="true"></fb:comments>` actually doesn't load anything (from what i can look at in the browser console… anything particular to specify in this snippet that i'm missing ?